# SSDT: File loop breaks for excel 2007 files

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have a file loop in Visual Studio SSDT 2017.

It's using the excel connection manager 
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";" and a excel file path variable to load excel macro enabled templates into a SQL database from a network folder.

This is all working fine with excel 2010, 2013, 2016 etc but is failing when
a user saves a template with excel 2007, if the file is re-opened and saved with excel 2010 or above then the file loop works fine again.

I tried numerous things but can't the excel 2007 files processing without re-opening in excel 2010 and clicking save, any ideas on this, I've tried a whole load of things?

Thanks

Comment: there is a JET connection string for pre-2010 excel files. In order to process both you need to check the extension for XLS or XLSX and apply the correct conn string

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did come across that but I'm still not sure on this. The ACE.OLEDB.12 connection works fine for excel 2007 when no file loop is used. Both excel 2010 and 2007 are saved as .xlsm files so the file formats are the same. I wonder what changes when the file is saved in excel 2010? Not too sure what to do with this